# curl 400 bad request (in bash script)

Tags: bash, curl, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I trying to do execute the following script in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
source chaves.sh
HEAD='"X-Cachet-Token:'$CACHET_KEY'"'
SEARCH="'{"'"status"'":1,"'"id"'":"'"7"'","'"enabled"'":true}'"
echo $SEARCH

if curl -s --head  --request GET http://google.com.br | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null; then 
   echo 'rodou'
   curl -X PUT -H '"Content-Type:application/json;"' -H '"'X-Cachet-Token:$CACHET_KEY'"' -d $SEARCH $CACHET_URL/7

else
  echo 'não deu'
  curl -X PUT -H '"Content-Type: application/json;"' -H $x -d '{"status":1,"id":"7","enabled":true}' $CACHET_URL/7
fi
```

But keep receiving a 400 bad request from the server.

When i try to run the same line (echo in the script, Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v) directly in terminal, the command run without problems.

The source file have the directions to path and a variable token i need to use, but as far as i have tested is reading ok.

- edit 1 - hidding some sensitive content

  edit 2 - posting the exit line (grabed trought Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v)

The command i neet to input in server is:

> curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json;" -H
>   "X-Cachet-Token:4A7ixgkU4hcCWFReQ15G" -d
>   '{"status":1,"id":"7","enabled":true}'
>   http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/api/v1/components/7

And the exit i grabed trought echo comand, give me the exact exit i want, but don't run inside script, only outside.

I'm a bit new to the curl, any help can be apreciate.

Sorry for the bad english and tks in advance.

Comment: The `$SEARCH` looks botched but we don't know exactly what the server expects. Can you [edit] the question to show a case where the query works with a static PUT request?

Comment: Welcome to bash scripting character escape madness. To make it easier, first thing to do is start taking out reserved chars you don't need. For curl headers, just do: -H 'content-type: application/json' and not -H '"content-type: application/json"'. For X-Cachet-Token you can do header="X-Cachet-Token: ${CACHET_KEY}" and in curl -H $header

Comment: Also you should try your curl commands (inside the script) with "--trace-ascii /dev/stdout" so you can actually see what the curl is sending (payload, url, headers, etc) to the server. You can actually see what you're doing wrong then and work on that instead of probably be changing stuff that is actually working :)